Does 1=1 in join condition affect the inner join execution time
Does 1=1 in a join condition affect the inner join execution time?
Assume table1 is a very large table with 500 million records.
Is there a difference in the following SQL joins  execution times and flow/steps of the join
in Azure Databricks?
Query 1
select *
from table1 A
join table1 b
  on 1=1 -- <- Here
  and b.date between a.Date-10 and a.date

Query 2
select *
from table1 A
join table1 b 
  on b.date between a.Date-10 and a.date



think about it logically, how could it have any effect at all on the query performance? its a fixed outcome, and will be removed from any query plan generated 2) why don't you try it an see? Compare the execution plans of each.


And you have tagged conflicting RDBMS... SQL Server is not the same as Azure Databricks.

In SQL, you tell the system what you want, not how to do it. A 1=1 condition should be easily optimized out by any reasonably competent query planning engine. Certainly anything available commercially should be doing so.

Using 1=1 in the join condition will force a Cartesian product, which is extremely inefficient for large tables. Even though Databricks is a distributed system designed for handling large datasets, the performance degradation caused by 1=1 will be significant.

@PrathikKini OP is not using 1=1 as the only join condition, its in addition to a regular join condition. So will have not effect on anything at all.

Other question: Why write such nonsense in the query?

@JonasMetzler it can actually make it much easier to debug a query because you can comment out any of the conditions (when you have multiple each on their own line) without having to change where to and or join to and. But from a logic perspective its meaningless.

@JonasMetzler Perhaps dynamic SQL? Often is is convenient to have a WHERE 1 = 1
or ON 1 = 1 as an anchor to freely add and remove AND some-condition.

My guess is OP has inherited the code and doesn't know what it does. Or has a supervisor who has told them its bad for performance and to remove it. Who knows, maybe OP will tell us whats really going on.

Since the condition 1=1 is trivial to evaluate, the evaluation by itself should have negligible impact on performance, if not optimized out. I guess the real question is does the extra condition interfere with SQL Server's ability to efficiently use an index when joining to table2?  The execution plans in this fiddle would seem  to indicate no impact. Both plans appear identical, using index seeks for the join. (I also tried it with a left join, with similar results.)

I heard some people do such things to make it easier to debug their code. But if this is the reason, I wouldn't care about performance. The performance of a query that won't be used in "real life" doesn't matter ;)

Some people knowing it has no performance impact might leave such a construct in production code :shrug:

I've removing the conflicting tags. Please add back the single relevant RDBMS tag when you clarify your question.

In SQL Server adding a redundant 1=1 will block Simple parameterization of that query - so not entirely the same behaviour as without  that predicate.

@MartinSmith how do you know that? Is there a reference somewhere? (I couldn't see it in the attached link)

@DaleK - "Appendix A When Does SQL Server Not Auto-Parameterize Queries?" in the "plan caching and recompilation in sql server 2012" document - one of the items in the list is "• When a query contains comparison between two constants. For example, WHERE 20 > 5"

So it would be possible to come up with an example where a query was auto parameterised and that prevented a filtered index being matched but the 1=1 stopped that

Good to know! Thanks

If 1=1 affects query execution time, throw the product away, ask for your money back.

I agree with the concept that the 1=1 might have been introduced when they are generating queries in bulk from some config table - assume a table containing source tables and joining key - if the joining key is null use 1=1 or else use actual joining key...
